# python re: * is not greedy

Tags: python, greedy, regex-greedy

I think I'm missing something.  I was under the impression that * was greedy.  I'm executing the following code:

```
m = re.search('b*', 'abb')
print (m.group())          
print (m.group() == None)
```

The first print statement prints nothing, the second prints False. So I'm assuming that the search is matching the empty string.  Why doesn't it match 'bb'?

Interestingly, when I replace the * with +, the search matches 'bb' showing that + is indeed greedy.

```
m = re.search("b+", "abb")
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) it returns *the first match* - as `*` means zero or more, the first match is an empty string.

Comment: Common beginner mistake. You have to remember that the match start is also greedy; it'll try possible start locations beginning at the front of the string.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @user2357112: *"the match start is also greedy"* doesn't make sense. A common beginner mistake perhaps?